# AWS CDK Api Gateway Models Ref Dependency - Model reference must be in canonical form

Tags: node.js, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to add multiple models in the same time using aws CDK when one of the models is referencing the other one.
Ex:

```
  "Gender": {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "modelName": "GenderModel",
    "schema": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "Not Specified",
        "Male",
        "Female",
        "Non-Binary"
      ],
      "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "title": "GenderModel"
    }
  },
```

and

```
"Requirements": {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "modelName": "RequirementsModel",
    "schema": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "gender": {
          "ref": "https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/${Token[TOKEN.791]}/models/GenderModel"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "gender",
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "title": "RequirementsModel"
    }
  },
```

When i deploy this fails with

`Model reference must be in canonical form`

From what i can see this fails because the `GenderModel` does not exists. If i first add the `GenderModel` in the stack and then i add the `RequirementsModel` and deploy again it works just fine because the `GenderModel` was previously created. If i want to create both of the models in the same time it will fail.
I tried to make sure the order of `addModel` call is correct but it seems it does not work.

**Solution Found**

Seems like you have to add explicitly specify the dependency.

```
modelB.node.addDependency(modelA)
```

This will avoid the error and add the models in the correct order

Comment: as a reminder, it's better to create an answer to your own question and accept that one than to stuff the solution into the question and accept an answer that was not the solution. It makes it easier for people to use the Q/A in the future. Please update your post accordingly.

Comment: This looks like the solution I need as well. This isn't a very well documented issue online. I was wondering if you wouldn't mind shedding a little more light on this issue. Are you still using the ref inside of gender along with addDependency or only addDependency?  I need to accomplish the same thing but I have multiple models that have references to multiple models and I am curious how to utilize this exactly for that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/${Token[TOKEN.791]}/models/GenderModel`, specifically the `${Token[TOKEN.791]}` part. When the API is not created, at CloudFormation synthetisation time, id is not known and placeholder value used - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tokens.html

You can use the `Ref` intristic function to compose model by the reference

```js
const getModelRef = (api: RestApi, model: Model): string => 
    Fn.join(
        '',
        ['https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/',
        api.restApiId,
        '/models/',
        model.modelId]);
```

Comment: That was not actually the issue since i am already using that. Was able to fix this by just adding dependency between models. `model2.node.addDependency(model1)`

Comment: Okay, please consider updating your post to make clear the problem resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    "ModelCountry":
    {
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Model",
        "Properties" : {
            "ContentType" : "application/json",
            "Description" : "Country",
            "Name" : "Country",
            "RestApiId" : {"Ref": "WebApi"},
            "Schema": {
                "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                "title": "ModelCountry",
                "properties": {
                    "Id": {"type": "number"},
                    "Name": {"type": "string"},
                    "Alpha2Code": {"type": "string"},
                    "Alpha3Code": {"type": "string"},
                    "NumericCode": {"type": "string"},
                    "PhoneCode": {"type": "string"}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "ModelState":
    {
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Model",
        "DependsOn" : "ModelCountry",
        "Properties" : {
            "ContentType" : "application/json",
            "Description" : "State",
            "Name" : "State",
            "RestApiId" : {"Ref": "WebApi"},
            "Schema": {
                "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                "type": "object",
                "title": "ModelState",
                "properties": {
                    "Id": {"type": "number"},
                    "Name": {"type": "string"},
                    "Country": {"$ref": {"Fn::Join" : ["", ["https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/", {"Ref": "WebApi"}, "/models/", {"Ref": "ModelCountry"}]]}},
                    "Alpha2Code": {"type": "string"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```